# Media Upload to custom database and Custom Directory

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, uploads, media-library, wp-filesystem

I started developing a Plugin.I wanted to keep a form where the user can send an input text and a video/image to the website.The image should enter into the folder and the URL of the image/video should enter into the database.I tried the below code, but it is not functioning.

```
$title=$_POST["title"];
$tags=$_POST["tags"];
$filetmp=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $filetype=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
    $filepath="if_images/".$filename;
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
$sql="INSERT into imageupload(title,tags,imagepath) values('$title','$tags','$filepath')";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
    echo "inserted";
}
```

Comment: `wp-content` is the only directory you can reliably write to, if you are developing a public plugin. I would also recommend using WordPress media upload functions and native tables rather than trying to reinvent wheels.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you didn't create table `imageupload` or can't create folder `if_images` at your plugin folder.

As a proposal I suggest you to use built-in Wordpress functions and wordpress tables or create table on plugin activation.

To create new table use function [dbDelta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins).
If you want to upload user files, use well-documented `wp_handle_upload` function.

For example:

```
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
```

More [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload)

To create new row in you database, use `$wpdb` class.